# Mongoose $near query returns parse error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

This is an object example:

```
{
    "_id" : "581994",
    "type" : "Feature",
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            -149.0133,
            64.7439
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the query I execute:

```
        Earthquake
            .find({
                geometry: {
                    $near: {
                        $geometry: {
                            type: 'Point',
                            coordinates: [lon, lat]
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .exec(function(err, results) {

                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }

                return reply(results);
            })
```

and this is the model schema I have created:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.set('debug', true);

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var earthquakeSchema = new Schema({
    geometry: {
        type: String,
        coordinates: [Number]
    }
});

earthquakeSchema.index({
    geometry: '2dsphere'
});

var Earthquake = mongoose.model('Earthquake', earthquakeSchema);

module.exports = Earthquake;
```

From my perspective it seems correct but when I execute it I get always the same error:

```
[Error: Can't use $near with String.]
```

I don't find where is the mistake. I have checked everywhere

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have found out the solution:

I have to add default field corresponding to 'Point' to property 'type'. Now it works

Comment: May I know how did you do it ? Can you update your answer.